# Is it possible Render MVC control using a method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

We are working on an MVC application. As per requirement, we need to populate a VIEW using a method. I have created a sample application. You can see the method which is using to generate control in `Helper.cs` class under “Controller” folder. When we directly placing the `@Html.TextBox("SampleTextBox")` code in the view it is rendering correctly. But when we generate the same code using a method, it is not rendering properly and it is showing as a plain string.
If anybody has any idea regarding this please let us know, it would be very helpful.
[Sample code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ooggh6kxwoef1bc/RenderCode.zip?dl=0)

Instead of adding the following code directly to view, we need to populate it  using a method.

```
@Html.TextBox("SampleTextBox")
```

That is some thing like

```
@Html.Raw(Helper.GetStringCode())
```

Method:

```
public static string GetStringCode()
 {
            return "@Html.TextBox(\"SampleTextBox\")";
 }
```

Comment: Please add relevant code to the quesiton. No one will download zip file to test your project.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question.

Comment: So you want to render stuff using the default HTML Helper in your own code? Then create an extension method which accepts the default HTML Helper as a parameter, and do your calls on that.

Comment: Why you want to use Razor if you can create dynamic HTML string. What is the purpose of returning razor code from the back? You should return partial view in this case and use as much razor as you want in partial view.

Comment: are you trying to generate different types of controls based on some condition?

Comment: Actual purpose is we need to generated code for kendo mvc grid programmatically . We need to set the grid header name, tool tip programmatically which are configured somewhere in the project

Answer (score 0):

You could add a partial view for the Kendo Grid in the Shared folder and add an Html helper extension that returns your partial view:

Partial view `Shared/_KendoGrid.cshtml`:

```
@model CustomViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().Grid()...)
```

Html helper method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString KendoGrid(this HtmlHelper helper, string header)
{
    return helper.Partial("Shared/_KendoGrid", new CustomViewModel { Header = header });
}
```

In your `.cshtml`:

```
@Html.KendoGrid("Custom header")
```